# Using integral comparison to estimate how fast the partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1{k^3}$ converge

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation

> Consider the following infinite sum and its partial sums.
>
> $$ S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k^3} $$
>
> $$ S_N = \sum _{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k^3} $$
>
> Use integral comparison to estimate how fast  $S_N$  tends to  $S$ . That is, show that  $0<S−S_N<CN^{−q}$  giving the best values you can for the constants  $C$  and  $q$ .

My work is as follows:

The lower Riemann sum is given by $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3}$. The upper Riemann sum is  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3}$.

Since $ S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k^3} $, the the lower Riemman Sum is $S-1 = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3}$.

Thus, $S-1 < \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^3} < S$. We could evaluate the improper integral if it converges, however it shows to be inconclusive. It happens to be equal to $\zeta(3)$, however that is out of scope of the class I am taking and it is not accepted.

I don't know where to go from there. Also, what can I do with $ S_N = \sum _{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k^3} $, I am stuck on how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
$$\int_{N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3}\; dx < S - S_N = \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}
< \int_{N}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3}\; dx $$
In fact, you can do slightly better: since $1/x^3$ is convex for $x > 0$,
$$\int_{N+1/2}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3}\; dx \ge \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} $$

Comment: Thanks, however, any hints on how to find $CN^{-q}$? I don't seem to follow

Comment: The integral is smaller than $1/2 N^{-2}$ (which is the first estimate)